# android List<> .size () cause application to crash

Tags: android, list, crash

In my application I have an object called Product and list of my products that is defined as following

```
List<Product> products;
```

when the list has items there is no problem and it works fine. but once it's empty, application crashes on the line I'm trying to see if it's empty.
this is  the line that I try to check if the List is empty or not.

```
if(products.size() > 0){
   // do somethig
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your *products* is null.

```
if(products==null){
    //do sth 
    return;
}

if(products.size() > 0){
   // do somethig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize your products `list`

```
List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize list before getting its count.
change to `List<Product> products=new ArrayList<Product>();`